# Input PHP Variable into HTML Select Tag

Tags: php, html, html-select

I have a php variable (`$list`) that is a list of values separated by commas.  I am trying to figure out how to convert or input this variable into a HTML select tag.  Here is what I have so far:

```
$dbquery = @$db->query('SELECT * FROM Company');
while ($queryText = $dbquery->fetchArray()){
  $array[]=$queryText['Company_Name'];
}
//the next batch of code, which is not included, converts the $array[] into a variable named $list//  
//the values for $list are: Company1, Company2, Company3, Company4...//

//HTML select tag//
echo '<select name="testSelect" id="testId">';
echo '<option value="'.$list.'">'.$list;
echo '</option></select>';
```

I understand that I would need a loop like a "while" or a "for" to list the values within $list, but I am not sure of the exact syntax.  Can anyone assist me with this?

Thanks,

DFM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) the list into an array (if you can't use `$array` directly for some reason) then do:

```
$listArray = explode(', ', $list);
echo '<select name="testSelect" id="testId">';
foreach ($listArray as $item)
    echo '<option value="'.htmlspecialchars($item).'">'. htmlspecialchars($item) . "</option>\n";
echo '</select>';
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll need an `option` element for every list item (company name).

```
<select name="testSelect" id="testId">
    <?php foreach ($array as $companyName): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $companyName; ?>"><?php echo $companyName; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: This does what you are after, although it skips the `$list` step (you don't need to create the `$list` variable unless you are using it somewhere else in your code as well.

Answer (score 0):

See [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

You can simulate the implode() function with a loop and string concatenation.

For example:

```
$out = '';
$append = ', ';

for($arr as $v)
{
  $out .= $v.$append;
}

$out = substr($out, 0, (-1) * strlen($append));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you converting the array into a comma separated list in the first place? Once you have an array you can do

```
foreach ($company in $list) {
    echo '<option value="' . htmlspecialchars($company) . '">' . htmlspecialchars($company) . '</option>';
}
```

to output your options. If you for some reason really need to have the comma separated list step, you can always use explode(',', $list) to convert it back to an array.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like `explode()` to put the list of stuff into an array, then loop through that.. something like:

```
$myArray = explode(",", $list);

echo "<select name=\"testSelect\" id=\"testId\">\n";
for($i = 0; $i < count($myArray); $i++) {
    // add each option to select list..
    echo "<option>" . $myArray[$i] . "</option>\n";
}
echo "</option>\n";
```

More on PHP `explode()` function:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php